# Why is this not printing to standard output (stdout)?

Tags: c, debugging, process, pipe, pid

I'm currently creating my own command line shell, and I'm having problems when trying to take in pipes. My program starts with the parent process. It checks to see if the user puts in exit or history. If so it uses those commands, but this is not important. If the user puts in anything other than exit or history, then it creates a child who executes the current task.

However, if the user puts in a command that has a single pipe, then we start at the parent and it creates a child process, call this child, child 1. child 1 see's that there is a pipe and uses fork to create another child, call this child 2. Child 1 creates another child, call it child 3 (Note: child 2 and 3 use shared memory). Now, child 2 executes the first command, and child 3 executes the command using child 2's output. But I'm not getting any output for some reason.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of executing my task, but this is what my professor said to do.

If you want to see all of my code here it is: http://pastebin.com/YNTVf3XP

**Otherwise here is my code starting at child 1:**

```
            //Otherwise if we have a single pipe, then do
            else if (numPipes == 1) {

                char *command1[CMD_MAX];        //string holding the first command
                char *command2[CMD_MAX];        //string holding the second command
                int fds[2];                     //create file descriptors for the parent and child
                pid_t new_pid;                  //create new pid_t obj

                onePipeSplit(tokens, command1, command2, numTokens);    //Getting each command for pipe

                if (pipe(fds) < 0) {            //use the pipe command. If < 0
                    perror("Pipe failure.");    //we have an error, so exit
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                //Creating child 2
                new_pid = fork();

                //if pid < 0 then we have an error. Exit.
                if (new_pid < 0) {
                    perror("Fork failure.");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                //Else we have the child (2) process
                else if (new_pid == 0) {

                    close(fds[0]);      //Close read

                    //sending stdin to the shared file descriptor
                    if (dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO)<0) {
                        perror("Can't dup");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    execvp(command1[0], command1);  //Execute the next command
                    perror("Exec failure");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                //Else if we have the parent process
                else {

                    pid_t child = fork();           //Creating child 3
                    if (new_pid < 0) {              //if pid < 0, error, exit
                        perror("Fork failure.");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    //else if pid > 0 we have the parent wait until children execute
                    else if (new_pid > 0) {
                        wait(NULL);
                    }

                    //else we have the child (3)
                    else {

                        close(fds[1]);      //Close write

                        //Sending stdout to the shared file descriptor
                        if (dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                            perror("Can't dup");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        execvp(command2[0], command2);  //Execute the command
                        perror("Exec failure");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is an image that my professor gave me to show how it should work.
[image: pipe]

Comment: I think you have too many children.  If you have `foo | bar` you need one pipe and two more processes (besides the one your program already is).  So parent creates a pipe, `p`  Parent forks 1st child (this will be `bar`).  Child : `close(p[1]); dup2(p[0], 0); exec("bar");` Now parent forks 2nd time (this will be `foo`).  Child: `close(p[0]); dup2(p[1], 1); exec("foo");` Parent: `close(p[0]); close[p[1]); wait for children`.

Comment: @J.V.A. I have added an image to the question showing what my professor gave me. Doesn't this imply that there should be 3 children in total? I could be wrong however.

Comment: I'm not sure what function shell(1) is doing, but if that's how the professor wants it done, then that's the right answer :)

Comment: @j.v.a Okay, do you see why it's not printing to stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
                   pid_t child = fork();           //Creating child 3
                    if (new_pid < 0) {   
       ... you keep checking `new_pid` here on down,
       ... but you should be checking `child` here on down...
```

Also in `onePipeSplit` you need to put a NULL at the end of both command lists because `execvp` needs that.  After the first loop add:

```
command1[i] = NULL;
```

and after the second:

```
command2[i] = NULL;
```

OK, a few more fixes:

after each dup2() you need to close the original fd.  One example:

```
                    if (dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO)<0) {
                        perror("Can't dup");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    close(fds[1]);      /* ADD ME */
```

and in the parent process:

```
                    //else if pid > 0 we have the parent wait until children execute
                    else if (child > 0) {
                        close(fds[0]);   /* we don't use */
                        close(fds[1]);   /* the pipe */
                        wait(NULL);
                        exit(0);         /* when 2 & 3 are done, we are too */
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That fixed a weird bug, but unfortunately it still doesn't print out to stdout. I will keep looking, but so far I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You got the second one `else if (new_pid > 0) {` too, right?

Comment: Yes. I just tried getting rid of the second fork, so now shell(2) executes the first command and pipes to shell(1) and it works. That is really odd that it doesn't work when I'm using 2 children...

Comment: I think you need to keep the 3 processes if that's the way your prof wants it.

Comment: I definitely agree, I just thought I would try it out to see if the bug was somewhere else.

Comment: With those 4 changes your code seems to work for me.  I can do: `date | tr : ~` and get the expected output.

Comment: The command you showed me worked. But when I try ls -e | sort, it doesn't work.

Comment: That fixed the ls -e | sort ! Thank you so much, you've honestly saved me a ton. Would you mind to take a look at my 3 pipe command now? I understand if you don't want to haha you've just been a great help!

Comment: @j That's completely fair. Thanks again!